unable to retrive number of helm releases as an integer using python
I am using python to interact with a kubernetes cluster. I am trying to retrieve the number of releases by using the following code:
number_of_releases = subprocess.getoutput(f"helm history myRelease --namespace myNamespace -o json | jq length")

When I run print(number_of_releases) I get 2 (which is my expected result from using normal kubectl) and running print(type(number_of_releases)) shows that this is a string. However, when I try to use int(number_of_releases) I get an error saying invalid literal for int() with base 10.
I have tried no_whitespace_variable = number_of_releases.strip() but curiously the length of the variable no_whitespace_variable turns out to be 205. Does anyone know what might be happening, or have any further suggestions for troubleshooting?

I'd try very very hard to avoid running subprocess commands as strings.  Can you call ['helm', 'history', 'myRelease', '-o', 'json'], then json.loads() the result?  Now you'll have the list of releases as a native Python object and you won't have to worry about the shell interactions.

still doesn't work
